# ElasticSearch - is aggregation only perform on term?

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose I use `keyword` tokenizer and `lowercase` filter, thus my `my_name` field "It is a Nike shoe." is tokenized to only one ***term***: `["it is a nike shoe."]`.

Use aggregation query:

```
{
"size": 0,
"aggs" : {
    "my_aggs" : {
        "terms" : { "field" : "my_name" }
    }
}}
```

It returns

```
"aggregations" : {
    "my_aggs" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [ {
        "key" : "it is a nike shoe.",
        "doc_count" : 1
      } ]
    }
  }
```

So I think aggregation is act on term. Which means I cannot get original `desc` field "It is a Nike shoe.".

My question is:

1. Is aggregation only perform on ***term***, which means aggregate by term?
2. For my case, is it possible to get original `my_name` field using aggregation (I want to know unique `my_name` values, not after tokenized term...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Top hits Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) can include more info, we can include original name. Aggregation can also work together with `bool` query, which makes it very flexible.

Here is a sample, we group by "brandName":

```
curl -XGET 'my-elasticsearch.com/test-aggs/_search?pretty=true' -d '{
  "size": 0,
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [ {
        "match" : {
          "state" : {
            "query" : ["Active"],
            "type" : "boolean"
          }
        }
      }, {
        "match" : {
          "brandName" : {
            "query" : "nik",
            "type" : "phrase_prefix"
          }
        }
      } ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "my_aggs": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "brandName"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "my_top_hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1, // for each term, how many matched "hit" are return ("_source" is included in "hit")
            "_source": {
              "include": "brandName"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Sample output:

```
{
  "took" : 37,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 10,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "my_aggs" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [ {
        "key" : "nike inc. international company",
        "doc_count" : 6,
        "my_top_hits" : {
          "hits" : {
            "total" : 6,
            "max_score" : 1.1467223,
            "hits" : [ {
              "_index" : "test-agg",
              "_type" : "Brand",
              "_id" : "AVFMf2jW9vvU7GxqHawa",
              "_score" : 1.1467223,
              "_source":{"brandName":"Nike Inc. International company"}
            } ]
          }
        }
      }, {
        "key" : "nike company",
        "doc_count" : 3,
        "my_top_hits" : {
          "hits" : {
            "total" : 3,
            "max_score" : 1.5016319,
            "hits" : [ {
              "_index" : "test-agg",
              "_type" : "Brand",
              "_id" : "AVFMjXOl9kfxoaJKgdxV",
              "_score" : 1.5016319,
              "_source":{"brandName":"NIKE Company"}
            } ]
          }
        }
      }, {
        "key" : "nikee...",
        "doc_count" : 1,
        "my_top_hits" : {
          "hits" : {
            "total" : 1,
            "max_score" : 1.6866593,
            "hits" : [ {
              "_index" : "test-agg",
              "_type" : "Brand",
              "_id" : "AVFMjaXi9vvU7GxqHawe",
              "_score" : 1.6866593,
              "_source":{"brandName":"NIKEE..."}
            } ]
          }
        }
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

Original "brandName" is returned.

While there is big limitation:

For term "nike", there maybe several "brandName" tokenized to "nike". E.x: ["NIKE", "NIKE", "Nike", "nike", "NIKE", "Nike", "Nike"]. That means it is impossible to specify "size" in "top_hits", because we don't know how many "brandName"s are tokenized to term "nike" (that makes no benefit than return all results and you program to get unique records).

Another cons is that aggregation is not high performance, it is much slower than match/term query.

Answer (score 1):

1)Yes, Aggregations are only performed on **terms** stored in *Inverted Index*

2)Yes, You can get the original value using [top hits aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html)

Try this

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "my_aggs": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "my_name",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "include_original": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "_source": {
              "include": "my_name"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

Does this help?

Comment: This is helpful! But there is other limitation for "top hits", please see my answer.